# file_put_contents copying empty downloaded file on server but works well on localhost

Tags: php, file, url, download, copy

Hi i need to copy a downloaded file from url to server for this i am using the

```
file_put_contents("down.csv", fopen("http://www.example.com.au", 'r'));
```

This is working fine on my localhost and copy the downloaded file content to down.csv but on live server it copes the empty file.

Please suggest what can be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There was a http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0  now it is enabled on server and its working fine

thanks